# Unable to start Oracle listener as root user

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle10g

I want to start Oracle Listner as root user. I am able to start listener as oracle user.
But its not starting as root user.
I am able to stop and check status as root user.

When I start listener as root it gives following messages:-

```
# lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 08-MAY-2012 15:08:11

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/102/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

/opt/oracle/102/bin/tnslsnr: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00517: Lost contact
   Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe
```

Please help me to start listener as root user.

Comment: Just don't do that. Start it as the oracle user.

Comment: but requirement is that only. I want to start it as root. is there any alternative so that at runtime i can have oracle user.

Comment: Where does that requirement come from? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: see.. I have an script file which connects with oracle. we call it agent. if i run this script as root then listner doesn't work. If i run that script as oracle then it works. I can't run that script as oracle always because it used in some other places also.

Comment: can SUID will be useful in this case???

Comment: Use `su` or `sudo` in your script. No, don't use setuid.

Comment: if i use su then then script will always run as oracle user. I dont want to do that.As this script is being used in some other places.

Comment: I want some way which will run my script as oracle whenever i want otherwise it should run as root.

Comment: what is the harm with setuid??? what is the main purpose of this???

Comment: Use su or sudo **inside** your script.

Comment: if i use su then then script will always run as oracle user. I dont want to run that script as oracle user always.

Comment: Anji, please read what I typed. You use su or sudo **inside**, **as part of**, in some of the lines **in** your script. You don't run your script with su.

Answer (score 2):

You should not run Oracle as root user, it's a security risk. There is not a single reason to run the rdbms and/or the listener as root user, unless you completely messed up the installation, that also is not even allowed to run as root.

If you do feel a need to run the listener as root user, make sure that your environment variables are correct. In your case:

```
   # export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/102
   # export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

   # cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
   # chmod u+s lsnrctl
   # lsnrctl start
```

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2012 20:51:07

> Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting /data/oracle/base/product/se_10205_s/bin/tnslsnr: please
>   wait...
>
> TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production System parameter
>   file is /data/oracle/base/admin/network/listener.ora Log messages
>   written to
>   /data/oracle/base/product/se_10205_s/network/log/listener.log
>   Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER)))
>
> Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER)))
>   STATUS of the LISTENER
>   ------------------------ Alias                     LISTENER Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production Start Date
>   09-MAY-2012 20:51:09 Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0
>   sec Trace Level               off Security                  ON: Local
>   OS Authentication SNMP                      OFF Listener Parameter
>   File   /data/oracle/base/admin/network/listener.ora Listener Log File 
>   /data/oracle/base/product/se_10205_s/network/log/listener.log
>   Listening Endpoints Summary...
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER))) The listener
>   supports no services The command completed successfully

```
# lsnrctl stop
```

> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2012
>   20:52:16
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER)))
>   TNS-01190: The user is not authorized to execute the requested
>   listener command

Don't do this; if you do you make a mistake. Pick any other user that is member of the dba group but not root.

BTW: after this little demo I had to fix a little issue:

> Started with pid=5215 Error listening on:
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER))) TNS-12555:
>   TNS:permission denied  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
>   TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation    Linux Error: 1:
>   Operation not permitted

problem was - obvious - that /var/tmp/.oracle/sLISTENER was owned by root. A little chown to the correct user took care of that.

Comment: thanks for the help...I understood this. I want to know that I have one script by which i start the listener. that script has root permission. if I change the permission  to oracle then it starts listener successfully otherwise it fails. If i give suid to that script then it will work or not???? for ex-- chmod u+s abc.sh

Comment: No, setuid on scripts is ignored. Setuid only works on binaries. You could make use of a lsnrctl script that is in your root PATH before $ORACLE_HOME/bin that performs the su to oracle.